# cannot open train.lua: No such file or directory

Tags: lua, torch

When i run

```
th train.lua -data_file data/demo-train.hdf5 -val_data_file data/demo -val.hdf5 -savefile demo-model
```

it outputs that:

```
/home/XXX/torch/install/bin/luajit: cannot open train.lua: No such file or directory  
stack traceback:  
    [C]: in function 'dofile'  
    .../XXX/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks/trepl/scm-1/bin/th:150: in main chunk  
    [C]: at 0x55a17891c570
```

i using cuda toolkit 10.2 , ubuntu 18.04 ,lua 5.4.2

Comment: do you have a file called train.lua?

Comment: i have file called train.lua

Comment: either the file does not exist or you don't have read permission

Comment: when i add "sudo",it shows "[C]: in function 'dofile'
 /usr/lib/torch-trepl/th:149: in main chunk
 [C]: at 0x55a5bc21d1d0
"

Comment: i don't know why ,however it solved.   When i input the command sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends libhdf5-serial-dev liblmdb-dev
and reboot